# Cannot find Brother printer (MFCJ5830DW) over Wired Network connection

Tags: printer, wired-networking, brother-printer

I have new work laptop, Windows 11, connected to my home network. I tried connecting/adding my home printer, a Brother MFCJ5830DW.

I found the printer's TCP/IP address (192.168.1.248) and tried to add manually using the "Change Printer Settings" > Add Manually  > Add a printer using an IP address or hostname, but it didn't work.

I watched [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy2XnjFDEfo), which meant I downloaded and installed [the driver](https://www.brother-usa.com/support/mfcj5830dw).
I tried installing the "Full Driver & Software Package (Recommended)" but still it could not find the printer. Again I tried to add manually using the printer's TCP/IP address (192.168.1.248), but it didn't work...

I also read some help articles:

- [https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/66811/~/no-devices-could-be-found-over-the-network-message-when-installing-the](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/66811/%7E/no-devices-could-be-found-over-the-network-message-when-installing-the)
- https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=fax5750e_us&faqid=faq00002636_000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the [Brother help article](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/66811/%7E/no-devices-could-be-found-over-the-network-message-when-installing-the), I opened the command prompt and **sent a `ping 192.168.1.248`** (please note your printer IP address may be different than mine). The reply came back immediately (screenshot below).

After I did this, both the plain Windows "Change Printer Settings" > Add Printer, and the Brother "Full Driver & Software Package" UI's could locate the printer directly (I clicked "Refresh"), even without manually specifying the IP address...

**EDIT**

Note that the ping did not work when connected to my work VPN, it only worked once I **disconnected from my work VPN (temporarily)**. This means I can't print in my local/home-office printer while on work VPN, which is fine (someone please correct me if I'm wrong)

[image: screenshot of cmd ping 192.168.1.248 and seeing immediate replies, after pinging the printer, it coudl be added]